# Find a gem version via bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

Is there a way we can find a Gem version via bundler ?

**For eg**

```
$ bundle show capistrano 
/Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1
```

This gives me the version, but i don't want to play with splitting and finding the value via last index.

I tried it this way

```
a = `bundle show capistrano`
b = a.split("/").last
b.slice! ("capistrano-")
puts b

$3.2.1
```

The above does my work, but is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: The quickest/simplest way I can think of is to open Gemfile.lock and look there

Comment: Or `bundle exec gem list | grep capistrano`

Comment: Well, it still returns like `capistrano (3.2.1)
capistrano-comx (0.7.3)`.  I just need the number like **3.2.1**

Comment: Could you describe how you want to use this?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, i updated my question with the way i tried and what i need as output

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this information programmatically like so:

```
Gem.loaded_specs['capistrano'].version.to_s #=> "3.2.1"
```